# How do I stop the execution of HttpConnection.getInputStream()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, urlconnection, httpsurlconnection

**Problem**

I am running the method `HttpsUrlConnection.getInputStream()` inside of `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` that runs from a `DialogFragment`.

I want it to terminate when the user exits the fragment.

If I don't, useless data will keep loading in the background.

**What I tried**

I tried setting the `URLConnection` object to `null` in the `onDismiss()` callback, but it doesn't stop the `getInputStream()` method from executing. 
I can't call `mConnection.disconnect()` in the UI thread, and it would be ineffective in another AsyncTask, since they're executed sequentially.

`AsyncTask.cancel()` is not useful since it won't stop the `doInBackground()` method.

**Question**

How do I force a return from the getInputStream() method?

---

**Code**

As per @CarlosRobles request, here is the code of my doInBackground()

```
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    setCurrentConnection((HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection());
    mCurrentConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(mSSLSocketFactory);
    mCurrentConnection.connect();

    int responseCode = mCurrentConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode >= 400) {
        throw new IOException("Bad response code");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "response code: " + responseCode);

    // TODO: Should call .close() if IOException happens here?
    InputStream inputStream = mCurrentConnection.getInputStream();

    String response = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

    inputStream.close();
    mCurrentConnection.disconnect();

    return response;
```

---

**Other considerations**

I just checked the execution time of all the function called in the snippet above, and I just found that `UrlConnection.getResponseCode()`, is by far the function taking the most time to run. I suppose it's due to the call to `UrlConnection.getInputStream()` inside of it. Later, the inputStream is always cached into the connection object, that's why `UrlConnection.getInputstream()` takes almost no time in my function.

Comment: How about manually call 
`mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
mTask.cancel(true);`

Comment: Have a look at [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). They have a good model to handle terminated Activities. Maybe you can copy some ideas from there. And you don't have to call mConnection.disconnect from UI-Thread. Just set a volatile flag and check this flag in your downloading logic.

Comment: @Elshan I already do that. It's not effective, read the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the UI you can call `AsyncTask.cancel(true);` and in the `doInBackground()` you can keep calling `isCancelled()` to detect if the function has to abort, after that you can do whatever you need

As we can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> Cancelling a task A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking
>   cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to
>   isCancelled() to return true. [...] To ensure that a task is
>   cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return
>   value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if
>   possible (inside a loop for instance.)

in your  `doInBackground`you have the function  `convertStreamToString` function. That is the longest operation, and inside it for sure you can interrupt the download. For usre inside it you have any kind of loop to retrieve the content of the stream and save it to a string, and there is where you can abort it.

```
 private void convertStreamToString () {    


            //..


           //loop to convert StreamToString
           {
               //..

              // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) {
                 mConnection.disconnect()
                 break;
             }
           }

   }
```

Comment: I have no loop running in my onBackground(), so as I mentioned in my answer, I can make no use of `AsyncTask.cancel()`. Maybe you've got some idea on how to use it in conjunction with `HttpsUrlConnection.getInputStream()`? That would be sweet.

Comment: but getInputStream has not a lot of time, that just gets the input stream and i suppose after that somewhere you read the stream, and that can be done in a loop and can be interrupted. Can you paste the code of the AsyncTask?

Comment: I just init a connection and read the stream. I edited the question to let you see the code.

Comment: Maybe you want to say it's not the getInputStream that takes time when  the 3G signal is low? Because I assure you, sometimes that method takes more than 10 seconds to return.

Comment: wow, thats too much. i cannot say, but what im sure is that the longest operation is to get the content of the stream. Actually, you have to take a look at your convertStreamToString function. That is the longest one, and inside it for sure you can interrupt the download

Comment: It's not like you say. The convertInputStreamToString(...) took less than half a second. On the other hand, the execution from the start to the first Log.d(...) in the code I posted, took almost one minute in a place with poor connection. Tested with another logic to read the stream but it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: I just checked the execution time of all the function called in the snippet above, and I just found that UrlConnection.getResponseCode(), is by far the function taking the most time to run. I suppose it's due to the call to UrlConnection.getInputStream() inside of it. Later, the inputStream is always cached into the connection object, that's why UrlConnection.getInputstream() takes almost no time in my function.

Comment: good information. in the project im working in right now, for any reason that methods are faster but what you says make sense. I will try to find out what actually happens in getInputStream and if i can come up with something ill be back!

Comment: Both `getResponseCode` and `getInputStream` have to wait until the server has started sending data back. This can take quite some time depending on the network. Currently, and perhaps forever, there is no way to stop a thread that is running `getInputStream`, even interrupting the thread doesn't work; see the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037462/